# How to update expandable list view values

Tags: android, expandablelistview, updating

Hi I am using expandable list view in my layout which contain list of fitness activities i have done on that particular day. I can see all the list of activities when i initially open my Activity. But when i add new activities, i can not see new activities in my expandable list view. How can i see my new activities when i come back from other screens? Please suggest me some solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to update expandable list view values in android

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is that after adding activity, bind the adapter again with your listview. Make sure whatever array, you bind with list view using adapter, gets updated after you add activity.